# Adding RSA keys to the iPhone keychain

Tags: iphone, cryptography, rsa, keychain

I'm trying to add a public and private RSA keys to the iPhone's keychain, so I can use the CommonCrypto library, but am not entirely sure how to do that. The MYCrypto library seems to only work for the Mac and not the iPhone right now. Can anyone help and explain how to add a private/public key to the keychain and get a SecKeyRef to them?

Comment: How are you storing these keys? In a certificate or P12 package?

Answer (score 5):

So in iOS, the keychain is sandboxed, AFAIK. This means that whatever you put into the keychain is only accessible by your app and your app alone unless you specify otherwise. You have to enable *Keychain Sharing* under **Capabilities** in the project settings.

Now that that's out of the way, you can certainly import the data. Since they're `NSString` objects, you'd first have to convert that to `NSData` objects to import them correctly. Most likely, they're encoded in Base64, so you'lL have to reverse that:

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
```

Now that that's done, you can use this method to both save your key to the keychain and get the SecKeyRef:

```
/**
 * key: the data you're importing
 * keySize: the length of the key (512, 1024, 2048)
 * isPrivate: is this a private key or public key?
 */
- (SecKeyRef)saveKeyToKeychain:(NSData *)key keySize:(NSUInteger)keySize private:(BOOL)isPrivate {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData *tag;
    id keyClass;

    if (isPrivate) {
        tag = privateTag;
        keyClass = (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate;
    }
    else {
        tag = publicTag;
        keyClass = (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic;
    }

    NSDictionary *saveDict = @{
            (__bridge id) kSecClass : (__bridge id) kSecClassKey,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyType : (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrApplicationTag : tag,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClass : keyClass,
            (__bridge id) kSecValueData : key,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeySizeInBits : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:keySize],
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrEffectiveKeySize : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:keySize],
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrCanDerive : (__bridge id) kCFBooleanFalse,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrCanEncrypt : (__bridge id) kCFBooleanTrue,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrCanDecrypt : (__bridge id) kCFBooleanFalse,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrCanVerify : (__bridge id) kCFBooleanTrue,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrCanSign : (__bridge id) kCFBooleanFalse,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrCanWrap : (__bridge id) kCFBooleanTrue,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrCanUnwrap : (__bridge id) kCFBooleanFalse
    };

    SecKeyRef savedKeyRef = NULL;
    sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) saveDict, (CFTypeRef *)&savedKeyRef);
    if (sanityCheck != errSecSuccess) {
        LOGGING_FACILITY1(sanityCheck != noErr, @"Problem saving the key to keychain, OSStatus == %d.", sanityCheck);
    }

    return savedKeyRef;
}
```

Later, if you want to retrieve the SecKeyRef from the keychain, you can use this:

```
- (SecKeyRef)getKeyRef:(BOOL)isPrivate {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData *tag;
    id keyClass;
    if (isPrivate) {
        if (privateKeyRef != NULL) {
            // already exists in memory, return
            return privateKeyRef;
        }
        tag = privateTag;
        keyClass = (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate;
    }
    else {
        if (publicKeyRef != NULL) {
            // already exists in memory, return
            return publicKeyRef;
        }
        tag = publicTag;
        keyClass = (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic;
    }

    NSDictionary *queryDict = @{
            (__bridge id) kSecClass : (__bridge id) kSecClassKey,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyType : (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrApplicationTag : tag,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClass : keyClass,
            (__bridge id) kSecReturnRef : (__bridge id) kCFBooleanTrue
    };

    SecKeyRef keyReference = NULL;
    sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) queryDict, (CFTypeRef *) &keyReference);
    if (sanityCheck != errSecSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Error trying to retrieve key from server. isPrivate: %d. sanityCheck: %li", isPrivate, sanityCheck);
    }

    if (isPrivate) {
        privateKeyRef = keyReference;
    }
    else {
        publicKeyRef = keyReference;
    }
    return keyReference;
}
```

### About privateTag and publicTag

`privateTag` and `publicTag` are used to mark the `kSecAttrApplicationTag` which defines the application that uses this key. You want to have a separate `privateTag` and `publicTag` to differentiate between your private key and public key.

It's a bit convoluted because I followed the sample code, but I defined my `privateTag` and `publicTag` this way:

*SecKeyWrapper.h*

```
#define kPublicKeyTag           "com.sample.app.publickey"
#define kPrivateKeyTag          "com.sample.app.privatekey"
```

*SecKeyWrapper.m*

```
// just under @implementation or @synthesize lines
static const uint8_t publicKeyIdentifier[] = kPublicKeyTag;
static const uint8_t privateKeyIdentifier[] = kPrivateKeyTag;

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // Tag data to search for keys.
        privateTag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:privateKeyIdentifier length:sizeof(privateKeyIdentifier)];
        publicTag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier length:sizeof(publicKeyIdentifier)];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then use the `privateTag` and `publicTag` as you would in the code samples I provided above.

Comment: @thanks mikeho for the code. I am getting savedKeyRef = nil with sanityCheck = 0 first time, after that each time sanityCheck = -25299 and message "Problem saving the key...".  While privateKeyRef and privateKeyRef always returned as nil with sanityCheck = 0. Could you please help me?

Comment: @SaurabhShukla: I added some information regarding the privateKeyRef and publicKeyRef. The problem that I suspect is that the privateTag and publicTag are not set correct, so that means that it's not actually saving the data to the right place. See my addition to the answer and give it a try.

Comment: I solved it in another way. I am adding my answer. +1 for the direction you given to me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you generating them on the iPhone? If so, [this message](http://lists.apple.com/archives/apple-cdsa/2009/May/msg00051.html) plus the [example code](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW9) in the Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Programming Guide should steer you in the right direction. If not, I'm working on some code that should accomplish that--it's not quite there yet.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792097/import-rsa-keys-to-iphone-keychain).

[MyCrypto says that it works on the iPhone](http://mooseyard.com/projects/MYCrypto/Documentation/html/index.html). What kind of problems are you seeing?

Comment: No, the limitations for MYCrypto specifically say that it runs into problems at runtime with the iPhone. I get an OSStatus parameter error (-50) when I try to import the public key.

Comment: Yeah, Jens Alfke is working hard on it but it's pretty clear from his correspondence on the CDSA mailing list that he's cracking a *very tough nut* and it's going to be a while before he's got a readily-consumable library.

Answer (score 0):

The code which works for me to add public key into iOS keychain is below:

```
- (NSData *)stripPublicKeyHeader:(NSData *)d_key
{
    // Skip ASN.1 public key header
    if (d_key == nil) return(nil);

    unsigned int len = [d_key length];
    if (!len) return(nil);

    unsigned char *c_key = (unsigned char *)[d_key bytes];
    unsigned int  idx    = 0;

    if (c_key[idx++] != 0x30) return(nil);

    if (c_key[idx] > 0x80) idx += c_key[idx] - 0x80 + 1;
    else idx++;

    // PKCS #1 rsaEncryption szOID_RSA_RSA
    static unsigned char seqiod[] =
    { 0x30,   0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01,
        0x01, 0x05, 0x00 };
    if (memcmp(&c_key[idx], seqiod, 15)) return(nil);

    idx += 15;

    if (c_key[idx++] != 0x03) return(nil);

    if (c_key[idx] > 0x80) idx += c_key[idx] - 0x80 + 1;
    else idx++;

    if (c_key[idx++] != '\0') return(nil);

    // Now make a new NSData from this buffer
    return([NSData dataWithBytes:&c_key[idx] length:len - idx]);
}

- (BOOL)addPublicKey:(NSString *)key withTag:(NSString *)tag
{    
    NSString *startPublicKey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
    NSString *endPublicKey = @"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

    NSString *s_key = NULL;

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:key];
    [scanner scanUpToString:startPublicKey intoString:nil];
    [scanner scanString:startPublicKey intoString:nil];
    [scanner scanUpToString:endPublicKey intoString:&s_key];

    // This will be base64 encoded, decode it.
    NSData *d_key = [RSAKeyHandler base64DataFromString:s_key];
    d_key = [self stripPublicKeyHeader:d_key];
    if (d_key == nil) return(FALSE);

    NSData *d_tag = [NSData dataWithBytes:[tag UTF8String] length:[tag length]];

    // Delete any old lingering key with the same tag
    NSMutableDictionary *publicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [publicKey setObject:d_tag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)publicKey);

    CFTypeRef persistKey = nil;

    // Add persistent version of the key to system keychain
    [publicKey setObject:d_key forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic forKey:(__bridge id)
     kSecAttrKeyClass];
    [publicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)
     kSecReturnPersistentRef];

    OSStatus secStatus = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)publicKey, &persistKey);
    if (persistKey != nil) CFRelease(persistKey);

    if ((secStatus != noErr) && (secStatus != errSecDuplicateItem)) {
        NSLog(@"Release public key");
        return(FALSE);
    }

    // Now fetch the SecKeyRef version of the key
    SecKeyRef keyRef = nil;

    [publicKey removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    [publicKey removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];
    [publicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef
     ];
    [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    secStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)publicKey,
                                    (CFTypeRef *)&keyRef);

    //[publicKey release];

    if (keyRef == nil) return(FALSE);

    // Add to our pseudo keychain
    //[keyRefs addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&keyRef objCType:@encode(
    //                                                                    SecKeyRef)]];

    return(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. To add a little bit of context for this answer, what @SaurabhShukla is trying to do is add an externally generated public key to his iOS device. This requires stripping out a header that iOS doesn't need. The opposite is true if you want to send a locally-generated public key to a server as well.

Comment: The source of this code is: http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/